# Laravel Log::info next line character not working

Tags: php, laravel, logging

I am using the laravel and trying to log the messages.

```
Log::info('[ProductViewModel/validate] First line message. \r\nSecond line message.');
```

Why `\r\n` not working and just show the output like below.

```
[2016-03-21 10:17:43] local.INFO: [ProductViewModel/validate] First line message. \r\nSecond line message.
```

Answer (score 18):

you can use PHP_EOL as line break

```
Log::info('[ProductViewModel/validate] First line message'. PHP_EOL .'Second line message');
```

Answer (score 3):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes around your log message, like so:

`Log::info("[ProductViewModel/validate] First line message. \r\nSecond line message.");`

Tabs also work with this approach (using \t).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should allow it in formatter options like:

```
$logger = new Monolog\Logger('MyLoggerName');
$formatter = new Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter(
    null, // Format of message in log, default [%datetime%] %channel%.%level_name%: %message% %context% %extra%\n
    null, // Datetime format
    true, // allowInlineLineBreaks option, default false
    true  // ignoreEmptyContextAndExtra option, default false
);
$debugHandler = new Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler('/tmp/my_debug.log', Monolog\Logger::DEBUG);
$debugHandler->setFormatter($formatter);
$logger->pushHandler($debugHandler);
```

source: https://stepanoff.org/wordpress/2017/11/13/allow-inline-line-breaks-for-monolog/

Answer (score 1):

Use `."\n"` to go next line.

Comment: If would be great if you could expand your answer a bit more~

Answer (score 0):

```php
$data = [
    'user id' => 'id',
    'user verified email' => 'email'
];
$val = json_encode($data);
Log::channel('User_Activity')->info($val.PHP_EOL);
```

in json file happy Coding